# facebook login button added to my app but does not redirects once the user is logged in

Tags: javascript, facebook, html, facebook-graph-api

I am developing a web application and i have implemented facebook login from developers.facebook.com but the thing is that whenever the user log in with his facebook credentials it does not redirect to my application and also i am trying to test it locally in my IDE but even i am unable to do it. is there any ways to make it as well i am in search of log out option as i want add log out button after the user's logged in. any help would be appreciated. thanks in advance.

and here is my log in code:

HTML:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>

<div class="fb-login-button" data-width="500"></div>
```

and my JS code:

```
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  // init the FB JS SDK
   FB.init({
  appId      : '425369200906567',                        // App ID from the app dashboard
  channelUrl : 'channel.html', // Channel file for x-domain comms
  status     : true,                                 // Check Facebook Login status
  xfbml      : true                                  // Look for social plugins on the page
   });

   // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here
   };

   // Load the SDK asynchronously
       (function(d, s, id){
       var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

      (function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=425369200906567";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to do something once the user logs in to your app (your case redirect to another page **application page** you can use `response.authResponse` to do it

```
FB.login(function(response) {
      if (response.authResponse) {
          // when the user logs in! & gives permission
          // Do something
         alert('Change this alert to "windows.location"')
      } else {
          // when the user doesn't give the required permissions
          // Do something 
        alert('User canceled login or did not fully authorize the app.');

      }
    }, { scope: 'user_photos, publish_stream' }); // App's permission
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ct7sV/)

Comment: i have tried these example but even i have updated the Fiddle. but it does not redirects. any suggestions.? http://jsfiddle.net/Ct7sV/1/

Comment: [try this one (added /show to the permalink](http://jsfiddle.net/Ct7sV/3/show/) (the problem is that jsFiddle uses iframe which breaks the function `windows.location` & `windows.open`)

Comment: Thank you very much it really worked well. but cant i test it locally as i am not giving any Website URL location in edit app details in facebook.? and also i think there is some issue with my app http://jsfiddle.net/Ct7sV/4/

Comment: Your app is in `SandBox mode`, which make it available only to its developers, turn it off from [Here](http://developers.facebook.com/apps)

Comment: but the thing is that after the FB login it opens the next page in the new window is there any option to make it load in the same window after logged in?

Comment: Yes, you can redirect the user within the same window, using `window.location.href = 'http://example.com';` instead of `windows.open`